# How to handle missed sendPoll method quiz answers in Telegram bot API?

Tags: telegram-bot

Imagine that the bot you created sends a poll, and you want to handle a case when the user does not answer anything. As I already know, there is no upcoming update after this case, so the question is: **How to handle it?** Please help me guys.